# Duplicate Local Variable Passe + The Operator / is undefined for the argument type(s) String,Int

Tags: java

I'm a newbie at Java and I'm trying to do a tool to calculate a few stuff, I'm trying to setup a "GUI" for it but I'm having two errors:

Duplicate local variable passe and - and -The operator (* and /) is undefined for the argument types String/Int

What I've done so far:

```
    String total, lgnd, epic, rare, unc, passe, epicv, rarev, passev, money, money2, totalv, legendaryv, uncommonv;


    String lgnd = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Quantas skins lendarias/douradas voce tem?");

    String epic = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Quantas skins epicas/roxas voce tem?");

    String rare = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Quantas skins raras/azuis voce tem?");

    String unc = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Quantas skins incomuns/verdes voce tem?");

    String passe = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Voce tem quantos passes de batalha comprados?");        

    Integer.parseInt(lgnd);
    Integer.parseInt(epic);
    Integer.parseInt(rare);
    Integer.parseInt(unc);
    Integer.parseInt(passe);

    total = lgnd + epic + rare + unc;
    legendaryv = lgnd * 2000;
    epicv = epic * 1500;
    rarev = rare * 1200;
    uncommonv = unc * 800;
    passev = passe * 950;
    totalv = legendaryv + epicv + rarev + uncommonv - passev;
    money = totalv / 1000;
    money2 = money * 10;

    System.out.println("Voce tem "+total +" skins.");
    System.out.println("Com isso, voce gastou "+totalv +" V-Bucks na loja de itens.");
    System.out.println("Assim, gastando cerca de "+money2 +" dolares.");

}
```

}

Errors:

The operator * is undefined for the argument types String/Int
Duplicate Local Variable Passe

Answer (score 0):

You are defining variable twice & applying the * operator to String (not a number) which is not allowed.

How it should be.

```
 int total, lgnd, epic, rare, unc, passe, epicv, rarev, passev, money, money2, totalv, legendaryv, uncommonv;


       String lgnd_str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Quantas skins lendarias/douradas voce tem?");

        String lepic_str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Quantas skins epicas/roxas voce tem?");

        String lrare_str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Quantas skins raras/azuis voce tem?");

        String lunc_str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Quantas skins incomuns/verdes voce tem?");

        String lpasse_str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Voce tem quantos passes de batalha comprados?");        

      lgnd = Integer.parseInt(lgnd_str);
        epic = Integer.parseInt(epic_str);
        rare = Integer.parseInt(rare_str);
        unc = Integer.parseInt(unc_str);
       passe  = Integer.parseInt(passe_str);

        total = lgnd + epic + rare + unc;
        legendaryv = lgnd * 2000;
        epicv = epic * 1500;
        rarev = rare * 1200;
        uncommonv = unc * 800;
        passev = passe * 950;
        totalv = legendaryv + epicv + rarev + uncommonv - passev;
        money = totalv / 1000;
        money2 = money * 10;

        System.out.println("Voce tem "+total +" skins.");
        System.out.println("Com isso, voce gastou "+totalv +" V-Bucks na loja de itens.");
        System.out.println("Assim, gastando cerca de "+money2 +" dolares.");
```

What we did here is changed the type of variables from String to int, Created different String variables for string input, assigned parsed value to int variable defined earlier.

Comment: Bro you are such a God. Thank you so much. I'm starting at Java and having a lot of fun lol, thanks for the help.

Comment: *"How it **should** be"*? No, it should be that variables are not pre-declared, but declared when first needed, e.g. `int lgnd = Integer.parseInt(lgnd_str);` and `int epicv = epic * 1500;` --- You should only pre-declare when you have to, e.g. before a loop or an `if` statement.